# Using printf inside a string

Tags: c, string

I'm trying to put `printf("` in a string

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<conio.h>
main()
{
      char print1="printf(\""; \\i used \ as an escape sequence for "
      printf("%s",print1);
      getch();
}
```

but it gives me the following warning:

> 5 [Warning] initialization makes integer from pointer without a cast

and when I execute the code,the output is : `<null>`

Comment: `char print1` should be `char *print1`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This line

```
char print1="printf(\""; \\i used \ as an escape sequence for "
```

should be

```
 char *print1="printf(\""; \\i used \ as an escape sequence for "
```

or perhaps

```
char print1[]="printf(\""; \\i used \ as an escape sequence for "
```

Answer (score 0):

This is because, your assignment `char print1 = "...";` assigns a string to a single character, e.g. the compiler converts the string to an unsigned number. To resolve this, use `char *print1 = "...";` which will result in an *array* of characters.